# Excel formating column for date and time

Tags: c#, excel, formatting

The program i'm doing now has me grabbing info from our database and exporting it to an Excel file. This is the first time I've done this so, sorry for the stupid questions (possibly).

I am having problems formatting the date/time.

The database has the date/time as : 9/19/2013 5:30:00 PM

However, whenever it is exported to the Excel file the cell shows : 9/19/2013 17:30

I just want the military time to go away.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply whatever format you want to the excel cells manually at the end of the process, at the beginning by putting the data into a template or in code.

Also, you can link the spreadsheet directly to the data (subject to which RDMS you use), no program required!

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using custom formats directly in Excel then you can just write the data in your C# code using string formatters.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.85).aspx